# android zoomable and scrollable board game

Tags: android, zooming, scrollable

I'm developing a Android board game and have a question regarding creating a board that is zoomable and scrollable. The board contains a static background, characters (players) and  the actual "level" which is drawn using tiles.

My solutions is to have a collection of elements (tiles, figures, all game elements - all have x,y coordinates and width + height), a camera and a renderer that draws the collection according to cameraX,cameraY, cameraWidth and cameraHeight. So if a user would scroll to the right, the camera would just set the cameraX appropriately - and the surface is scrollable. And if a user would zoom in/out the renderer would just scale every element image appropriately.

Example code for the renderer with scrollable surface and zoom in/out

```
    protected function draw(Canvas c){
      Collection elements = collection.getElements(cameraX,cameraY,cameraWidth,cameraHeight);
      if(elements.size() > 0) {
         for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
              elements.get(i).drawElement(c);
         }
      }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    // element class drawElement function
    protected drawElement function(Canvas c) {
        if(this.image != null) {            
          int w = this.width;
          int h = this.height;
          if(this.zoomFactor < 1) {
             w*=this.zoomFactor;
             h*=this.zoomFactor;
          }
          c.drawBitmap(this.image,this.x,this.y,w,h);
        }
    }
```

- Is this the best solutions?
- Could it be achived somehow else?
- Could scrolling be achived using a ScrollView?

I dont wanna use any engine, because this is for a school project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can simplify this situation somewhat. If you are indeed seeking a flat texture plane that is simply distorted by perspective, the Android `Camera` class can help you. Do not confuse this with the hardware camera for taking photos. This camera is a helper class wrapped around a matrix to perform transformations on 2D objects. You can read more about this very complex rendering topic by googling "fast fourier transforms". Basically you will want to create a canvas and do your drawing in a completely 2D way. Then right before you draw to the screen, you should transform this canvas using the Camera class. Let me know if you need some clarification. There is a lot of cool mathematics going on behind the scenes!

Take a look at this sample from the Android API Demos

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html

Android `graphics.Camera` documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html

Comment: so if i understand correctly, u suggest that i draw the canvas and then using Canvas.scale()  and Canvas.save() implement the zoom feature? What about scrolling (should i do it as i described above)? Can u post a link regarding this class (all i get is the hardware camera). thanks

Comment: Correct! Seems like you get it. Instead of scrolling as described above, use the `Camera.translate(x, y, z)` method. You will want to translate about the X and Y axis to scroll around, and translate up and down the Z axis to zoom. Apologies for the missing link, it is difficult to find! The documentation is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html

Comment: thank you, u have been very helpful.. one more thing if i understand correclty u're method draws the whole level (which is about 2000x480 px) to the canvas (which is 480x800px) and than uses the camera class to to implement scrolling and zooming. But isnt drawing the whole level(2000x500) every frame abit to much?